# When should I use ParseError versus ValidationError in Django Rest Framework serializer?

Tags: django, forms, validation, exception, django-rest-framework

With Django Rest Framework, when should I be raising a `ParseError` versus a `serializers.ValidationError` when validating form data in a serializer?

My code looks something like this:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        if  'username' not in validated_data:
            raise ParseError({'username': ['A username is required.']})
        if  'password' not in validated_data:
            raise ParseError({'password': ['A password is required.']})
        if  'email' not in validated_data or len(validated_data['email']) == 0:
            raise ParseError({'email': ['An email is required.']})
        if UserModel.objects.filter(email=validated_data['email']):
            raise ParseError({'email': ['A user with that email already exists.']})

        # ...
```

Which of these, if any, should be `serializers.ValidationError` instead? And what rule should I follow in the future to determine which to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [DRF doc of **`ParseError`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#parseerror)

> **ParseError**
>   Raised if the request contains malformed data when accessing **`request.data`**.

Usually, this is handled by DRF itself. So, you don't have to explicitly raise it. 
In your case, all of the conditions are comes under [***ValidationError***](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#validationerror) section. So, it would be more appropriate to use the ***`ValidationError`*** rather than the `ParseError`.

---

**NOTE:** It's highly reccomend to use the [**`validate(...)`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation) method for ***object-level validation*** and [**`validate_<field_name>(...)`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation) method for ***field-level validation*** in Django RESTFramework. (It's not good to handle validation in `create` or any other methods, in DRF)